# Property of Beta function: $|B(a,b)|\le B(\Re(a),\Re(b))$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

I was reading about the property

$$|B(a,b)|\le B(\Re(a),\Re(b))$$

for any $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(a),\Re(b)>0$ (as principal-ideal-domain
mentioned in the comments), where $B$ denotes the Beta function

$$
B(a,b) = \int_0^1x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx.
$$

Is this just done by using the triangle inequality?

$$
\begin{align}
|B(a,b)|&\le \int_0^1|x^{a-1}|\ |(1-x)^{b-1}|\ dx \\
&=\int_0^1 |e^{\log(x) (\Re(a-1)+i\Im(a-1))}|\ |e^{\log(1-x) (\Re(b-1)+i\Im(b-1))}|\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1 e^{\log(x) \Re(a-1)}\ e^{\log(1-x) \Re(b-1)}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1 x^{\Re(a-1)}\ (1-x)^{\Re(b-1)}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1 x^{\Re(a)-1}\ (1-x)^{\Re(b)-1}\ dx\\
&=B(\Re(a),\Re(b))
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yeah, that looks correct. But you don't need so many lines for that. Simply prove once and for all that for $x>0$ and $s \in \mathbb C$ you have $|x^s| = x^{\Re(s)}$.

Comment: By the way: Your proof works of course only for $a,b \in \mathbb C$ with $\Re(a),\Re((b)>0$ since that's where the integral converges and the beta function can be defined by that integral.